# I would like to insert another =IF in this formel

Tags: sharepoint-online, column

I would like to insert another =IF in this formel, for example: =IF it says "Hello" I want the text to be the color green. Is that possible?

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Ev_x002e__x0020_sluttid] <=[$_x00c4_rende_x0020_p_x00e5_b_x00], '#ff0000', '#32CD32')",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "font-size": "14px"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact condition for the result to show? Is there any relation like AND/OR or separate conditions between `[$Ev_x002e__x0020_sluttid] <=[$_x00c4_rende_x0020_p_x00e5_b_x00]` and [$SomeField] = 'Hello' `?

Comment: Hello! No there isnt, but I think it should be.

Comment: Then what should be the conditions? and which condition will be checked first?

Answer (score 1):

You can have nested `IFs`. In the example below I am including a second if that is evaluated if the first one is false (a new IF inside the "else", if you are coming from a programming language that has that):

```
"=if([$field] <=[$another], '#ff0000', if([$field] == 'Hello', '#00ff00', '#32CD32') )"
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on [Pedro's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/276653/77489), there's a basic syntax to `IF` statements which could be useful in the future, however his answer should result in the effect you're looking for.

```
=IF( Initial-Condition,
    TrueStatement,
    FalseStatement
)
```

However, the `IF` statement is, in itself, a statement. So you can put another `IF` statement in the true or false sections similar to the following:

```
=IF( Initial-Condition,
    IF( If-True-Condition,
        TrueStatement,
        FalseStatement
    ),
    IF( If-False-Condition,
        TrueStatement,
        FalseStatement
    )
)
```

This could be used to create a [Binary Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) style logic that can have many different answers depending on the inputs/field values. The new calculated value will be whatever final statement you traverse to based off of your conditions in the `IF` statements.

** Please note, the spacing is just for visualization. You can remove the indents and newlines when putting the statement in your json.